# Eclipse 2020-03 Where is the relaunch button?

Tags: eclipse

Recently upgraded to Eclipse 2020-03 and I can't find the 'relaunch' button. I checked the Customize Toolbars options and even installed the Launch View plug-in but still can't find the option to display the relaunch button?

Sorry, I have been very busy, from my 2019-09 Eclipse IDE With EE, it's the button circled in red...

[image]

Within Eclipse, navigate to the Window -> Perspective -> Customize Perspective, scroll down to Launch and this is what I have in 2019-09 ...

[image]

But the 2020-03 version of Eclipse only has these options...

[image]

You can hover the mouse over the option and see that it is provided by something called the 'Launch' Action Set.

I noticed that the 2019-09 version has two Launch Action sets but the 2020-03 only has one?

2019-03 has two ...
[image]

2020-06 only has one ...
[image]

Can I somehow add another 'Action Set' to the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: What Launch View plugin? Is there a picture of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It was added by the Spring Tools Suite, after I installed that plugin the Launch toolbar set had the extra 'Relaunch' button.